# Is drawing an imagined person haram?

Tags: halal-haram, image, drawing

I have been drawing for two years and got amazing results in that time. Even people I don't know compliment me, but is drawing a character that came from your mind haram?

Ex: Paul Gilligan's "Poncho" from pooch cafe.

And if so is it haram to draw them eyes?

Answer (score 1):

> روي عن أبي هريرة قال : قال رسول الله { صلى الله عليه وسلم : أتاني جبريل ، فقال : أتيتك البارحة ، فلم يمنعني أن أكون دخلت إلا أنه كان على الباب تماثيل ، **وكان في البيت ستر فيه تماثيل** ، وكان في البيت كلب ، فمر برأس التمثال الذي على الباب فيقطع ، فيصير كهيئة الشجر ، **ومر بالستر فلتقطع منه وسادتان منبوذتان يوطآن** ، ومر بالكلب فليخرج . ففعل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم
>
> Translation: It was narrated that Abi-Horayra said: The messenger of Allah (peace and blessings be upon him) said: "Jebreel came to me and said: 'I came to you last night, and nothing prevented me to enter except that there existed statues before the door, **and there existed a cover (of cloth) containing images (of live-beings) in the home**, and there existed a dog in the home, so command that the head of the statue that is before the door - to be cut so it (the statue) has tree-like appearance, **and command that the cover to cut two outcast cushions (for feet) to be set in from it**, and command that the dog gets out.'" and so did the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings be upon him)

So we learn from this Hadeeth that we should not keep any dogs or images of life-beings or statues in the house because they prevent angels to enter it. So, logically, it is prohibited to make them up.

*And Allah knows best*.

Comment: This is about statuses and not drawings.

Comment: I have bolded text talking about drowings

Comment: Sir, images here doesn't mean drawings. Also I understand arabic and there isn't anything about drawings in the arabic version.

Comment: As you understand Arabic then تماثيل is the plural of تمثال it is a تفعيل of the source م ث ل and it means to make an identical image of something and no doubt a drawing is a kind of images, review the meaning of تمثال in the dictionaries (معاجم): http://www.almaany.com/home.php?language=arabic&word=%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84&cat_group=1&lang_name=%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A&type_word=2&dspl=0